# django-hosts force reload of a different urls.py

Tags: django

I am using [django-hosts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-hosts) to have different domain names point to one Django app.  The bulk of my Django app serves the site at mydomain.com, but one function handles short URLs at, say, mydoma.in.

Using django-hosts `default_urls.py` is what's used for mydomain.com and `short_urls.py` is used for mydoma.in.  One and only one of the `*_urls.py` files is loaded based on the domain of the request.

However, in two cases I seem to need requests to mydoma.in to know about `default_urls.py` to complete correctly.  Here is the relevant code from my views.py file:

```
def short_url(request, value):
    try:
        object = Object.objects.get(key=value)
        # (1)  Need to load default_urls.py here to /object URL is resolved
        return redirect (settings.BASE_URL + object.get_absolute_url(), permanent=True)
    except:
        # (2)  Need to load default_urls.py here to 404 page renders
        raise Http404
```

Is there a way to force the application to "switch" from `short_urls.py` to `default_urls.py` just before calling `redirect` and `raise`?

(I can't just copy the relevant routes from the one file to the other because then otherwise the URL would resolve under two domains.)

As possible work-around, I noted this code:

```
request.urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
```

So, alternatively, is there a way to replace `redirect` and `raise` which code that uses the `request` object with the updated `urlconf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import set_urlconf
set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
```